# How do I edit the dynamic data in an ASPX file?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm pretty new to dot net and my company is taking on a new client that uses it for their site.  They want me to edit the data in this string:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text="Description"/>
```

I need to figure out where said data is in order to edit it so does anybody know where I can find it or where to look to find it?  Sorry if this is a noob question :\

Comment: "Edit" how?  Do you need to build a form to edit this field on the page?  Do you need to trace where this field is getting its data?  Something else?  So far it's not really clear what you're asking, but it sounds like what you're looking for are introductory tutorials to ASP.NET: http://www.asp.net/web-forms

Comment: Unfortunately, Chad, your question just doesn't make any sense. There's no other data related to what you've posted. Can you be more specific about what needs to be changed? Otherwise, I'm not sure how anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: I apologize if the question doesn't make much sense.  There is an existing site with dynamic data coming in.  The data is called by the string above and I need to edit said data.  I'm asking where can I find the file to edit said data.

Comment: About the only thing I can even remotely suggest is to look for what's called the "codebehind" or "codebeside" file that accompanies the .aspx markup page. If its in C#, it will have a .cs extension; if it is in VB.NET, it will have a .vb extension. You'll have to search the code for the "lblDescription" id and see where its value is being loaded.

Comment: @Chad: That still doesn't make a lot of sense.  What file are you looking for?  What you're posted is server-side markup from an ASPX file.  It should have some associated server-side code (an `.aspx.cs` file?  maybe `.aspx.vb`?) which controls much of the dynamic UI logic.  Where the data itself comes from could be *anywhere*.  A database, hard-coded, a web service, some kind of calculation, user input, anything.  Again, you're going to want to start with some tutorials on how to write code in ASP.NET.  Setting a value to a label control is very basic.

Comment: If you look below clamchoda has answered my question.  Thanks to him.

Comment: There is no data in what you posted. There is only the literal string `"Description"`. There's nothing dynamic about that. Maybe the page has other "dynamic data", but there is none in that label.

Comment: I'm simply posting what I have in the file.  There are no other calls so I'm asking where would YOU look for the source of the data.

Comment: You are getting down-voted because everyone else on here apparently can't recall a time when they first encountered the .NET framework. Its certainly not obvious that the ASP:Label tag actually CREATES a 'hidden' variable of type 'Label' in the code-behind that you can't see declared anywhere. (FYI, its actually declared in the 'designer' file that you basically NEVER touch and sometimes can't even see, ASP.NET is weird like that.)

Comment: Having said that, if you truly didn't know where to look to see where/how that label is being set, then you REALLY aren't ready to do any production work in ASP.NET, and you really should spend some time in some beginner tutorials. Like any other framework, its easy to shoot yourself in the foot if you don't know how it works. The ASP.NET paradigm, in my opinion, is RADICALLY different from any other web framework I've seen.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate the advice and your understanding.  I rarely work in these files and honestly would rather never touch asp type stuff again but we have a random client that uses it and somehow I got stuck working on it.  The people here want me to spend hours learning 99% of what I don't need to know about a simple copy change.  Thanks again for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The data being progrmatically loaded in the code behind for the Label will look like this;

```
lblDescription.Text =
```

Do a search for `lblDescription.Text` to find out where it is being loaded from.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.  Other people seem to be very confused...

Comment: @GarryVass Take your own advice.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer